# Rails: trouble with pending / accepted invitations using :conditions hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm currently trying to make an app for uploading pics. there are users, albums, pics. The catch is that there can be multiple owners for each album, so in the form to create an album there is a check box portion where you highlight your friends names and "invite them" to be an owner. However I'm trying to make it so that an invite has to be "accepted" before ownership is shared. I'm trying to do this using a join table (`album_user`) and having a `album` and `pending_album`, which are distinguished by their `:status` when created

This is my

albums/new.html.erb (no issue here)

```
<%= form_for ([@user, @album]), :html => { :id => "uploadform" } do |f| %>
<div class="formholder">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>

    <br>
    <label>Hosts</label>
    <% @user.friends.each do |friend| %>
    <%= friend.name %>
    <%= check_box_tag 'album[user_ids][]', friend.id, @album.users.include?(friend) %>
    <% end %>

    <%= f.label :description %>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>

    <br>

    <%=f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

albums controller (issue here with status)

```
def create
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @album = @user.albums.build(params[:album].merge(:status => 'accepted'))
  @friends = @user.friends.find(params[:album][:user_ids])
  if @user.save
    for friend in @friends
      AlbumUser.create({:user_id => friend.id, :album_id => @album.id, :status => 'pending'})
      # friend.albums.build(params[:album].merge(:status => 'pending'))
    end
    redirect_to user_album_path(@user, @album), notice: 'Album was successfully created.'
  else
    render action: "new"
  end
end
```

user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

has_secure_password
attr_accessible :email, :name, :password, :password_confirmation, :profilepic
validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create

validates_format_of :name, :with => /[A-Za-z]+/, :on => :create
validates_format_of :email, :with => /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/i, :on => :create
validates_length_of :password, :minimum => 5, :on => :create
# validates :album, :uniqueness => true

has_many :album_users
has_many :albums, :through => :album_users, :conditions => {status: 'accepted'}
has_many :pending_albums, :through => :album_users, :source => :album, :conditions => {status: 'pending'}
accepts_nested_attributes_for :albums

has_many :friendships, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :friends, :through => :friendships, :conditions => "status = 'accepted'"
has_many :requested_friends, :through => :friendships, :source => :friend, :conditions => "status = 'requested'", :order => :created_at
has_many :pending_friends, :through => :friendships, :source => :friend, :conditions => "status = 'pending'", :order => :created_at

has_attached_file :profilepic

before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }

def name_with_initial
  "#{name}"
end

private

  def create_remember_token
    self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end
```

end

album model

```
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :description, :user_ids, :status
  validates_presence_of :name

  has_many :album_users
  has_many :users, :through => :album_users
  has_many :photos

end
```

album_user model

```
class AlbumUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :album_id, :user_id, :status
  belongs_to :album
  belongs_to :user
end
```

ISSUE HERE: users/show.html.erb (where I have an icon for each album, but it seems like when albums are being created, they aren't saving as `pending_album`s even though their :status is 'pending'.

```
    <% @user.pending_albums.each do |pending_album| %>
        <div class="albumthumb">
            <%= link_to image_tag(pending_album.photos ? pending_album.photos.first.avatar.url(:medium) : ("questionmark.png"), :size => "150x150"), user_album_path(@user, pending_album) %>
            <br>
            <%= pending_album.name %>
            <% if signed_in? %>
            <%= form_for(:album_user, :url => user_albums_path(:user_id => current_user.id, :album_id => pending_album.id)) do |f| %>
            <%= f.submit "Accept Invitation" %>
            <% end %>
            <% end %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
    <% @user.albums.each do |album| %>
        <div class="albumthumb">
            <%= link_to image_tag(!album.photos.empty? ? album.photos.first.avatar.url(:medium) : ("questionmark.png"), :size => "150x150"), user_album_path(@user, album) %>
            <br>
            <%= album.name %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
```

my issue is that the albums aren't saving as pending_albums. I thought my :conditions in the user model would help distinguish which are albums and which are pending albums? Everything seems to be falling under albums, even if they are supposed to be pending. Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you clarify why you want to have the "accept" step at all? I realize you're not asking for design input in your question, but why not just give out ownership and allow users to remove themselves from ownership. This would sidestep needing to have an "accept" step altogether. Has someone requested for there to be an extra step, like, "Oh, I really don't want to automatically see everything that's shared with me, I'd rather approve everything."  ?

Comment: What do you mean it is failing?  error messages\validation errors?

Comment: @normalocity because I want the user to be able to choose which albums he/she takes ownership of. This way they have more authority over what they participate in. Otherwise albums would pop out of no where every time a friend invites them to a new album.

Comment: @D3mon-1stVFW It's not saving properly, meaning the ones that I want to save under `pending_album` are just saving as `album`. I want it so that I can make an "accept/reject" link for the pending_albums, but when I log in as @user1 and make an album and invite @user2 and @user 3 and then logout and login as @user2, @user2.pending_albums is empty.